# I'm trying to switch frames in Selenium using Xpath, but haven't had any success so far

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to switch frames in Selenium using an Xpath instead of using the name of the frame. The frame doesn't have a name so I figured I could just use the Xpath, but I'm not sure Selenium supports using an Xpath instead of a name.

This is the normal way to switch frames:

```py
driver.switch_to.frame("WhateverFrame")
```

This is what I have tried:

```py
driver.switch_to.frame(By.XPath("//*[@id='ui-id-1']/iframe"))

driver.find_frame_by_xpath("//*[@id='ui-id-43']/iframe")
```

Any suggestions as to how I should alter my code to get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can switch to frame using different options.

```
driver.switch_to.frame('frame_name')
driver.switch_to.frame(frame_index)
driver.switch_to.frame(element)
```

So in your case you can **send the element** as shown below.

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ui-id-43']/iframe"))
```

Also you can do the below, if you want to go to first iframe.

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("iframe")[0])
```

Comment: I'll give this a try once I get back to work tomorrow. Looks like this should work to me!